# How to add custom taxonomy post count in main navigation menu in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I added the category post count in main navigation menu with the following code:

```
add_filter('the_title', 'wpse165333_the_title', 10, 2);

    function wpse165333_the_title($title, $post_ID)
    {
        if( 'nav_menu_item' == get_post_type($post_ID) )
        {
            if( 'taxonomy' == get_post_meta($post_ID, '_menu_item_type', true) && 'category' == get_post_meta($post_ID, '_menu_item_object', true) )
            {
                $category = get_category( get_post_meta($post_ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true) );
                $title .= sprintf(' (%d)', $category->count);
            }
        }
        return $title;
    }
```

Also I'd like to add post count to custom taxonomy menu items in main navigation.
I added the following code:

```
$taxonomy= get_taxonomy( get_post_meta($post_ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true) );
            $title .= sprintf(' (%d)', $taxonomy->count);
```

However, nothing happened.
How can I add post number to custom taxonomy menu items in main menu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a taxonomy count with the following:

```
get_term_by( $field, $value, $taxonomy );
```

Where:
$field = either id, name or slug
$value = the id,name or slug of the taxonomy you want to find
$taxonomy = the name of the taxonomy type
(see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

For example...

```
$my_taxonomy = get_term_by( 'name', 'Horror', 'books' );
$count = $my_taxonomy->count;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think wp_count_terms returns the number of terms not post count...

Comment: Changed my answer, try that instead :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to use get_term_by.